# How to save 2 variables with SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I tried to build an application, which should save two variables with `sharedPreferences` without writing the `sharedPreferences` code two times. So I wrote the code below and used the variable `nameKey` for the location where the value should be saved and I used `safeVariable` for the value which should be saved. I have two different variables which should be saved, `counter1` (value + 1 when button is pressed) and `counter2` (value - 1 when button is pressed). The problem I have is that both variables become smaller by one, but only one variable `counter2` should do so. Does someone find the mistake in my code?
That´s the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int counter1 = 0;
  int counter2 = 20;
  String nameKey = "eins";
  int safeVariable;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(
      () {
        counter1++;
        counter2--;

        nameKey = "eins";
        safeVariable = counter1;
        save();

        nameKey = "zwei";
        safeVariable = counter2;
        save();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<bool> save() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return await preferences.setInt(nameKey, safeVariable);
  }

  Future<int> load() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getInt(nameKey);
  }

  set() {
    load().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        safeVariable = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    nameKey = "eins";
    set();
    counter1 = safeVariable;

    nameKey = "zwei";
    set();
    counter2 = safeVariable;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Test"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You have pushed the button this many times:',
              ),
              Text(counter1.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
              Text(counter2.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
              FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: _incrementCounter,
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are assigning value to counter1 = safeVariable;

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until the end of save() operation like this:
In:

```
void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(
      () {
        counter1++;
        counter2--;

        nameKey = "eins";
        safeVariable = counter1;
        save();

        nameKey = "zwei";
        safeVariable = counter2;
        save();
      },
    );
  }
```

put "await":

```
await save();
```

If you want to store in SharedPreferences multiple values at once, You can only load/save a list of strings (List).
This is how to do:

```
prefs.setStringList("key", ["a","b","c"]);
```

If you have ints you need to convert each int to string.

```
List<String> mylist = ["$counter1","$counter2"];
```